# Calculate Time spent by users on the platform

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis, metabase

I'm trying to calculate the time spent by users on my platform on a weekly basis. I have the following api_request_logs table (*Note: each row is duplicate)

```
time                            user_id       url 
------------------------        -------       ----
January 6,2020, 08:56 PM           14           api\v3\user1
January 6,2020, 08:58 PM           14           api\v3\session 
January 6,2020, 08:59 PM           14           api\v3\notification 
January 6,2020, 09:01 PM           14           api\v3\announcements
January 6,2020, 09:02 PM           14           api\v3\user2 
January 6,2020, 09:28 PM           14           api\v3\session

[enter image description here][1]
```

I tried this query, however, it doesn't seems it is outputting correct calculation .

```sql
select  SUM(timespent) timespent, a.user_id as user
from (
    select  timestamp_diff(max(time),min(time),minute) timespent,  DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(date from time), day) as Time, a.user_id as user
    from (
    select * , (countif (start) over (order by time)) as  grp from (
    select *, ifnull (lag(url) over(order by time), '') !=url as start from logs.api_request_logs a
    INNER JOIN logs.cohort_members on a.user_id = cohort_members.user_id
    INNER JOIN `logs.cohorts` on cohort_members.cohort_id = `logs.cohorts`.cohort_id
    INNER Join logs.users on cohort_members.user_id = users.user_id
    WHERE a.user_id = 14  and time > timestamp ('2020-01-01 00:00:00') 
    )) group by user, grp)
    group by 2
    order by 2 asc
```

Current output:

```
timespent     users        Time 
---------     -------      -----
32 min         14       January 6,2020, 12:00 AM
```

Desired output :

```
Timespent    users       Time 
----------  --------     -----
  6 min      14          January 6,2020, 12:00 AM
```

What I'm doing wrong or do you have a better idea to do it?  Thanks

Comment: (1) Please explain the calculation; it is not obvious why you think the answer should be "6".  (2) What does "each row is duplicate)" mean?

Comment: @GordonLinoff 1: The total time spend (in minutes) by the users every day or every week. 2. Each row is duplicated with same time more than 10 times. I hope thats help

Comment: @GordonLinoff: it should be "6" because the user (14) spend one minute at each row.

Comment: . . No they didn't.  That user spent 26 minutes on the URL "api\v3\user2", according to the data in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I added a snapshot in my question, please have a look and let me know what you think?  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNR3b.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to group by your url as well ... try the following :-)

#standardsql :

```
SELECT
  SUM(timespent)   timespent,
  a.user_id AS user
FROM (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MAX(time),MIN(time),minute) timespent,
    DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(date  FROM  time), day) AS Time,
    a.user_id AS user
    ,url
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *,
      (countif (start) OVER (ORDER BY time)) AS grp
    FROM (
      SELECT
        *,
        ifnull (LAG(url) OVER(ORDER BY time),
          '') !=url AS start
      FROM
        logs.api_request_logs a
      INNER JOIN
        logs.cohort_members
      ON
        a.user_id = cohort_members.user_id
      INNER JOIN
        `logs.cohorts`
      ON
        cohort_members.cohort_id = `logs.cohorts`.cohort_id
      INNER JOIN
        logs.users
      ON
        cohort_members.user_id = users.user_id
      WHERE
        a.user_id = 14
        AND time > timestamp ('2020-01-01 00:00:00') ))
  GROUP BY
    user,
    gr,url)
GROUP BY
  2
ORDER BY
  2 ASC
```